# HTML code getting cut off

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've inherited the maintenance of a website that unfortunately doesn't seem to be working correctly. The last few lines of HTML code are getting cut off.

Page source shows this at the bottom:

### Movement

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="img/feettap_big.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Eye blink and muscle">Eye blink and foot tap</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_foottap_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
        <li><a href="img/flutter.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Eye Fluttering">Eye fluttering</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_flutter_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
        <li><a href="img/hiccups.png" rel="gallery" class="p
```

And then it just ends.

The site's address is: https://learningcentral.health.unm.edu/learning/user/onlineaccess/CE/eeg/artifacts/index.html

I think that link works even though it is a university site.

When I inspect the page with Firebug it shows some code for the piro_overlay and piro_table (the jQuery in charge of the pop-up images). Could that be the problem?

Actual source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>EEG Artifact Recognition</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mlo_drop.css" />
<link href="../css/allcourse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/eeg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/piro/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../js/stuHover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<!-- piro-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery_1.5-jquery_ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pirobox_extended_feb_2011.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.piroBox_ext({
    piro_speed :700,
    bg_alpha : 0.5,
    piro_scroll : true,
    piro_drag :true,
    piro_nav_pos: 'bottom'
});
});
</script>
<!-- end piro-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="coursetitle">
    <div class="series"><a href="../index.html">EEG Artifact Recognition</a> > <a href="index.html">What do artifacts look like?</a></div>
    <div id="coursetitle">
        <h1>EEG Artifact Recognition</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="top"><a href="../index.html" class="top_link"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="top"><a href="#nogo2" class="top_link"><span class="down">Lessons</span></a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="../intro/index.html">Introduction to EEG</a></li>
                <li><a href="../artifacts/index.html">What is an artifact?</a></li>
                <li><a href="../whatdo/index.html">What to do about an artifact?</a></li>
                <li><a href="../name/index.html">Name that Artifact</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top"><a href="../name/index.html" class="top_link"><span class="down">Name that Artifact</span></a></li>
        <li class="top"><a href="../ref/gloss.html" class="top_link" target="_blank"><span class="down">Glossary</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="arrows">
    <p><a href="../intro/notclean.html"><img src="../img/back.png" alt="back" align="middle" /></a>&nbsp;1 of 3 &nbsp;<a href="elec.html"><img src="../img/forward.png" alt="" align="middle" /></a></p>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h1>Artifacts: Rhythmical, repetitive, periodic or sustained</h1>
        <p>Rhythmical, repetitive, or periodic body movements and <a href="https://learningcentral.health.unm.edu/learning/user/onlineaccess/CE/eeg/ref/gloss.html#phys" class="gloss" target="blank">physiology</a> can often produce artifacts on the EEG that may be mistaken for activity coming from the brain. Many of these artifacts can be identified by closely watching the  patient, and noting when the activity occurs.</p>

    <h2>Muscle</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="img/chewing.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Chewing">Chewing</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_chew_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/frown.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="frown">Frown</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_frown_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/clench_big.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="jaw clench">Jaw Clench</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_clench_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/crying.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Crying">Crying</a></li>
        </ul>

    <h2>Movement</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="img/feettap_big.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Eye blink and muscle">Eye blink and foot tap</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_foottap_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/flutter.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Eye Fluttering">Eye fluttering</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_flutter_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/hiccups.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Hiccups">Hiccups</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_hiccup_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/phone.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Playing with phone">Game / phone playing</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_gameplay_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/nystagmus.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Nystagmus">Nystagmus</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/tremor.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Parkinsonian tremor">Parkinsonian tremor</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/scratch.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Scratch">Scratching head</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_scratch_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li>Tongue Movement&nbsp;-&nbsp;see <a href="pop_palatetic_vid.html" target="_blank">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/percussion1.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Physical therapy percussion">Physical therapy percussion</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/sway.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Head sway with respiration">Respiration sway</a></li>
        </ul>

    <h2>Physiological</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="img/ekg1.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="EKG 1">EKG 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/ekg2.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="EKG 2">EKG 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/pulse.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="Pulse artifact. Note that the peak in the Fz-Cz electrode follows the QRS in the ECG.">Pulse</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/sweat1.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="sweat1">Sweat 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="img/sweat2.png" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="sweat2">Sweat 2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there more code in the actual source?

Comment: Wait, so the code is there in the source code but is getting left off when being sent to the browser, right?

Comment: The rest of the code you see in firebug is generated by a jQuery plugin called Pirobox.

Comment: Its not the jquery or JS, if you disable it the issue persists. Your problem must lay in the source file or generating backend

Comment: I've seen a situation before where a server error caused output of the page to stop in a seemingly random place. I don't remember how I debugged or solved that particular problem though...

Comment: looks like the body is indeed being completed as you can see it when you inspect, but you cant see the end body tag when you view-source. The rest of the code is generated by the jsfile pirobox_extended_feb_2011.js

Comment: I don't think it's a JS thing. There is no end body tag, and changes from JS don't change the original source in chrome inspector. I say server problem: check logs.

Comment: can you post the PHP or whatever is creating that page on the server?  You are not going to find the problem by looking on the front end.